# Django View return JSON failed with CSRF

Tags: django, csrf

I wrote a simple Django view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt  # just add

@csrf_exempt
def handleRequest(request, intervention_code):
    result = {}
    norm_str = ''
    ........
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result), mimetype='application/json')
```

The view uses no template, just queries the database and returns the data in JSON format. 
I can retrieve the JSON object easily doing `http://myserver/myurl`

Unfortunately, I have to use a javascript library to make a POST AJAX request to get the same JSON object and I run into the typical Django CSRF failure.

When I do: `curl -d "sometext=foobar" http://myserver/myurl/` I got the same result.
I implemented all recommended CSRF middleware from Django doc, and still get the error.

Comment: This is not enough...Show us how you are sending the request to the server

Comment: Are you sending the CSRF token to the server when you do your ajax post?

Comment: Please elaborate more.  The AJAX call is made from javascript function called from normal html file

Comment: This wouldn't work you need to set the csrf token in your request

Comment: Thanks to Raunak, Timmy, and Daniel.  I updated the code to get it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's documentation [describes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) what you have to do to get CSRF working with Ajax.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Daniel pointed me to the Django doc and it worked now.  I chose to implement it without touching the ajax script.

Comment: the link is dead now